# R: force number of predictors in stepwise glm regression with stats::step()

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, glm

I have a Logistic model that I would like to perform stepwise variable regression on, forcing the number of output predictors to be 2

I know I can perform a similar task with `regsubset()` from [leaps package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/leaps/leaps.pdf) (as shown [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/37-model-selection-essentials-in-r/154-stepwise-regression-essentials-in-r/) as example), but it only works with linear models, while I need to use it on a `glm()` logistic model

Using an R built-in dataframe just as example that anybody can easily try:

```
MODEL <- glm( 'am ~ .', family=binomial(link='logit'), data = mtcars)
BACKWARD_MODEL <- step( MODEL, direction = "backward", scope = formula(~ .))
summary(BACKWARD_MODEL)
```

It return a model with 3 variables:

```
Call:
glm(formula = am ~ qsec + gear + carb, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)    360.96  484751.44   0.001    0.999
qsec           -41.21   38378.81  -0.001    0.999
gear           130.03  111642.78   0.001    0.999
carb           -39.31   41152.05  -0.001    0.999

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 4.3230e+01  on 31  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2.0927e-09  on 28  degrees of freedom
AIC: 8

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 25
```

How can I force `step()` to keep selecting until only 2 variables are left?

Comment: You can run `MASS::dropterm(BACKWARD_MODEL)` since you only want to drop one term. The 3rd model, the one without `carb`, has the smallest AIC.